# JQuery image fade speed

Tags: jquery

What is the syntax to assign a speed to each fade?

```
 function fadeIn()
{
   $(this).fadeIn( fadeOut );
}

function fadeOut()
{
   $(this).fadeOut( fadeIn );
}

fadeIn.call($("#myImage"));
```

Comment: Dude, it's right in the function documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ .  A little footwork of your own wouldn't hurt.

Comment: `var time_in_milliseconds = 1000;  $('#id').fadeOut(time_in_milliseconds);`

Comment: Thanks, i read the documentation but still couldnt maki it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is to pass in a number representing the number of miliseconds the effect will last, like this:

```
function fadeIn() {
   $(this).fadeIn(1000); // 1 second
}
```

You can also create a variable to store the number

```
var length = 1000;

function fadeIn() {
   $(this).fadeIn(length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider reading the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)? 'Cause you approach seems really too lazy.

It's clearly stated that you have `'slow'` (200ms) and `'fast'` (600ms) parameters as well as being able to specify the duration in milliseconds..

```
.fadeIn( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
```

Comment: Thanks, i did read the documentation but still couldnt maki it work. I'm not familiar with javaScript.